# Custom panoramic control with edge snaping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I am trying to create a ***'PanoramaControl'*** like control for Windows Phone 8, in terms that it displays a slideshow of scenes, each of them having the size of the ScreenWidth. I have tried using Microsoft's panorama control but I have abandoned this approach for several reasons:

- the amount of scenes is around 10-20, and it might be too much for PanoramaControl to handle, especially because there will be animation inside.
- I don't want the control to loop continuously, and PanoramaControl does.

After some research I decided to implement the control on my own, using a `ScrollViewer` and a `ListBox`, and the result is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RcqDMKn0EY (the movement is very smooth on both device and emulator, but is a bit choppy in the link due to screen capture)

What I am missing however, is the scene by scene snap-to-edge elastic functionality. 
I have tried playing with manipulation events, but I fail to get that smooth elastic inertial movement and I thought of asking for a suggestion towards an elegant implementation before getting the frustration up or worse.. hacking and compromising..

Therefore help or suggestions (even towards different approaches) will be greatly appreciated! :)

```
<Grid x:Name="layoutRoot">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="14*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox Name="listBoxScenes"  ItemsSource="{Binding Scenes}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Disabled" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedScene, Mode=TwoWay}">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0">
            <Grid Width="{Binding SceneWidth}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Contains the item name and the date-->
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName, FallbackValue=Item1}" Margin="9,30,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTime, StringFormat=D, FallbackValue='Sunday, May 11, 2014'}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```